# How can I get my Spring.net Webservice member attributes configured?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, spring.net

I am trying to setup a Spring.net web-service similar to the example at the following url:

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/springair.html

I have some questions regarding the member attributes on the service operations. The following xml setup injects in the attributes to the operations:

```xml
<property name="MemberAttributes">
  <dictionary>
    <entry key="SuggestFlights">
      <object type="System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute, System.Web.Services">
        <property name="Description" value="Gets those flight suggestions that are applicable for the supplied trip."/>
      </object>
    </entry>
    <entry key="Book">
      <object type="System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute, System.Web.Services">
        <property name="Description" value="Goes ahead and actually books what up until this point has been a transient reservation."/>
      </object>
    </entry>
    <entry key="GetAirportList">
      <object type="System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute, System.Web.Services">
        <property name="Description" value="Return a collection of all those airports that can be used for the purposes of booking."/>
      </object>
    </entry>
  </dictionary>
</property>
```

I have 2 questions around this. Firstly is it possible to access values from these attributes within AopAlliance.Intercept Interceptors? For example, is it possible to access the value of the Description property of the WebMethod Attribute, from within an interceptor? Possibly within the Invoke method and its IMethodInvocation parametter.

Secondly, is it possible to add custom attributes, derived from System.Attribute, similar to web method attributes outlined above and again access the properties of the attribute within an interceptor.

Any help on the above would be great!